# How add specified items to listbox from file?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have some text file and I want to load lines from line to line in the listbox, omitting the first and last line in this file. Can it be done ??

[image]

```
private void metroButton18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            listBox3.Items.Clear();

            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f.OpenFile()))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    listBox3.Items.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank You for Your help.

Comment: You could read the lines to a list and then omit the first and last index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**File.ReadAllLines Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) and skip the first and last index in the loop:

```
var path = @"C:\temp\MyTest.txt";
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

for(var i = 1; i < allLines.Length - 1; i++)
{
    listBox3.Items.Add(allLines[i]);
}
```

Using the **OpenFileDialog** to open the file:

```
OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    listBox3.Items.Clear();

    var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(f.FileName);
    for(var i = 1; i < allLines.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        listBox3.Items.Add(allLines[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read first line outside the loop:

```
line = sr.ReadLine();
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    listBox3.Items.Add(line);
}
```

After finishing reading from file, just remove last item:

```
listBox3.Items.RemoveAt(listBox3.Items.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?

```
OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f.OpenFile())) {
          string line;
          while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
                lines.Add(line); // add lines to list first
          }
    }
    string[] resultArray = lines.Skip(1).Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse().ToArray();
//skip first one , reverse so last one is the first now, skip again and reverse again to get actual list
    listBox1.Items.AddRange(resultArray);
}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: While this is ok answer, it looks too complicated for me. Also you probably want to have lines as `string[]` type, convert `ToArray()` and use `listBox1.Items.AddRange()` method in this case.

Comment: OP defined lines as List<string> so did I. Are you talking about this ? See edit please. @Reniuz

Comment: Yes. [Items.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) do not accept list of strings as parameter. Well it accepts but you probably will get only one item in list box with `List<string>` Type information in it.

Comment: You are right. Missed that, thanks. No need for second solution. @Reniuz

Comment: Still...you need to use `AddRange` :)